# DivisionByZero by using if else statements

Tags: java, exception, divide-by-zero

I have a small question that what is the use of `DivisionByZeroException` if we can handle with if else block. I tried with googling but cant get the proper answer. Can any one can tell me elaborately? Thanks in Advance

Comment: not a standard question

Comment: Will someone actually read the question?

Comment: In java it is [ArithmeticException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html)

Comment: You **should** be using if/else to catch a divide by zero and handle it.

Answer (score 6):

Forget about DivisionByZeroException, almost all the exceptions can be avoided by using if-else logic.

The whole point of Exceptions is to recover from some unexpected scenario and simplify this recovery. If there are 10 places where there is a chance for exceptions to occur in your code, you have to ensure you have included all the if-else conditions. Exception handling simplifies that. You don't have to verify at every possible place, just try them and catch if you get some exception at once place.

This also provides simple way of providing different ways of recovery mechanisms for different exceptions.

```
if(check for first type of exception)
{
   do first task
}
else
{
   return one type of error
}
do some intermediary task
if(check for first type of exception && check for second type of exception)
{
   do second task
}
else
{
   if(exception is of one type)
       return one type of error
   if(exception is of second type)
       return another type of error
}
```

the above code can be more clear if you use some try catch blocks as below...

```
try{
   do first task
   do some intermediary task
   do second task
}
catch(first type of exception)
{
   return one type of error
}
catch(second type of exception)
{
   return second type of error
}
catch(another type of exception developer may have forgotten)
{
   return a generic error
}
```

The second approach will obviously be more clear once you gained some good knowledge on Exception handling just like everybody else. The flow of code is more easily evident in second approach.

Comment: And adding another thing to what Buddha said.. Suppose you are using some third party api (JXL/JNA etc) .. You dont know what will happen if you pass the wrong values for arguments.. The function being called might have said "throws someException" (bad programming practice BTW )... In such scenario, you dont know what exception you will get.. If you dont know what exception you might get, how can you use if-else to prevent it???.. Using exceptions, you can catch it in a generalized way and handle it as "JXLException/JNAException.."

Comment: Yeah... Good point. You don't always know what to except.